# How to use NSMutableString as Condition in If Statement

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, asihttprequest, nsmutablestring

I have a webservice and ios application. I use  `ASIHTTPRequest.h, ASIFormDataRequest.h` headers to handle connection to my php scripts/mysql database

In one of the viewcontrollers I need to send multiple request to my web service and handle each response, and viewcontroller's view and methods are needed to refresh after each request.

`ASIHTTPRequest` has only one `(void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request` event so I need to handle my responses in blocks inside of `(void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request` to handle the request I come up with idea that maybe I can use a string and when request finishes i can use this string in if statement I wrote following code , but my condition in my requestfinish method `if ([checkRequest rangeOfString:@"like"].location != NSNotFound)` doesnt work

VoteMe.h

```
@interface VoteMe : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>{
 NSMutableString  *checkRequest;
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableString  *checkRequest;
```

Vote.m

```
@synthesize checkRequest;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [self showPicture];
}

-(void)showPicture
 {
     checkRequest =[NSMutableString stringWithString:@"showPicture"];

     //request a random picture url, from server
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:showpicture];
     ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

     [request setDelegate:self];
     [request startAsynchronous];
} 
-(IBAction)voteLike:(id)sender{

    checkRequest =[NSMutableString stringWithString:@"like"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:voteup];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];

    [self showPicture];

}
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{    

    if ([checkRequest rangeOfString:@"like"].location != NSNotFound) {
     //do smth
     }

    if ([checkRequest rangeOfString:@"showPicture"].location != NSNotFound) {
    //do someth else
    }
}
```

The problem of above code  when `-(IBAction)voteLike:(id)sender` is called it supposed to change string of `checkRequest` to "like" so when response of `ASIFormDataRequest` arrives if condition can work properly

In break points I see that checkRequest `Variable is not a CFString`

When I Use `Nsstring` instead of `NSMutableString` it is the same result

I know I need `retain` String then `release` afterwards but I Dont use `alloc` should I still need to `retain/release`

How can I achive my goal? Either a with better solution for checking if statement or fixing `NSString` and `NSmutableString` Issue above ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define something as a property (`checkRequest`), use `self.checkRequest` when you refer to it in code unless you have a **very** good reason not to.  Those attributes you put on the property statement get ignored if you access the variable directly.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that checkRequest is not a string when the request is finished is that it's released since you're never retaining it. You have created a retaining property but it's not used when you're accessing the instance variable directly.

For the checkRequest to be retained using your property, you have to write

```
self.checkRequest = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"like"];
```